# Jogos android criados no cocoon js não rodam no bluestacks

Tags: android, html5

Estou fazendo alguns testes com Construct 2 e Cocoon Js.
O .apk gerado pelo Cocoon Js roda normalmente em alguns celulares que testei, porém, nenhum deles funciona no Bluestacks. Ele começa a carregar o game, aparece o splash, mas depois fecha sozinho. Alguem tem alguma sugestão ou já passou por isso?
Minha preocupação é que como não roda no emulador, talvez não funcione também em alguns aparelhos.

Comment: Instale o [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat&hl=pt_BR) no `Bluestacks`, e verifique o que está acontecendo com seu app.

Comment: Valeu pela dica. O Catlog indica que o BlueStacks pulou a execução, com a mensagem: The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Estou rodando um app de testes para testar desempenho. Alguma dica para ele rodar. Basicamente eu vou criando sprites na tela para ver como fica o desempenho.

Comment: Testei com outros projetos, e também com alguns que sei que foram feitos da mesma maneira, Construct 2 e Cocoon JS, mas em todos ocorre o mesmo erro, nada roda. Alguma ideia?